# Hidden fasteners for 1/2" spacing between decking boards?

Tags: carpentry, screens

I want to build a screen out of 5/4 x 4 ipe boards with 1/2" spacing, using some sort of hidden fasteners. All the hidden fastener systems that I was able to find so far are designed for decking, and offer the maximum spacing of 1/4"... Is it possible to use one of these systems, but set the boards wider apart?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the deck brackets are installed board at a time, and the last bracket holds the next board.

The [Shadoe Track](http://www.shadoetrack.com/) however is a continuous rail, with conventional screws from below.  It can be set at any spacing.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! In my case this screen is on the wall, so there is no easy access from behind. I wonder, how feasible would it be to build sections of it on the ground and then attach to the wall...